# How to make a customized progressbar in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to learn how to make a progressbar like the one shown in this video.

I tried to replicate it in VS C#, but I get the error:

> C# Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

If I try using `if (txProgressBar.Text.Length == 85)`, I will get this in the TextBox (txProgressBar)

System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Syst...██

[Textbox Progressbar Tutorial VB 2010](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJNjTGongpc)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomizedProgressBar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int last = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txProgressBar.Text.Length = "85")
            {

                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Counted!");

            }else
            {
                if (last == 1)
                {
                    txProgressBar.Text = txProgressBar + "█";
                    last = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    txProgressBar.Text = txProgressBar.Text + "█";
                    last = 1;
                }
            }

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txProgressBar.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

`txProgressBar.Text = txProgressBar + "█";`

should be

`txProgressBar.Text = txProgressBar.Text + "█";` or `txProgressBar.Text &= "█";`

Comment: Awesome! I did the change. I also realized it was missing the *.Text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was the problem. The txProgressBar.Text = **txProgressBar** + "█"; was missing the *.Text. That solved the problem and the message is shown as well.